How to properly use pd.isna without type error
Attempting to use a function to fill up missing values in a religion column of my pandas dataframe, with the religion values of people living in the same house, I used the below code:
def fill_religion(row,grouped_data):
    
    if cd.isna(row['Religion']):
       
        home_group = grouped_data.get_group(row['House Number'], row['Street'])
        
        religions = home_group['Religion'].dropna().unique()
        
        if len(religion) == 1:
            return religion[0]
        else:
            return 'Unknown'
    
    else:
        return row['Religion']

# Group the data 
grouped_data = cd.groupby(['House Number','Street'])

# Apply the fill_religion function for missing values
cd['Religion'] = cd.apply(lambda row: fill_missing_religion(row, grouped_data), axis=1)

I got this error message:
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[109], line 25
     22 grouped_data = cd.groupby(['House Number','Street'])
     24 # Apply the fill_missing_religion function to fill the missing'Religion' values
---> 25 cd['Religion'] = cd.apply(lambda row: fill_missing_religion(row, grouped_data), axis=1)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:10347, in DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, by_row, engine, engine_kwargs, **kwargs)
  10333 from pandas.core.apply import frame_apply
  10335 op = frame_apply(
  10336     self,
  10337     func=func,
   (...)
  10345     kwargs=kwargs,
  10346 )
> 10347 return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:916, in FrameApply.apply(self)
    913 elif self.raw:
    914     return self.apply_raw(engine=self.engine, engine_kwargs=self.engine_kwargs)
--> 916 return self.apply_standard()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1063, in FrameApply.apply_standard(self)
   1061 def apply_standard(self):
   1062     if self.engine == "python":
-> 1063         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
   1064     else:
   1065         results, res_index = self.apply_series_numba()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1081, in FrameApply.apply_series_generator(self)
   1078 with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
   1079     for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
   1080         # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
-> 1081         results[i] = self.func(v, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
   1082         if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
   1083             # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because
   1084             #  series_generator will swap out the underlying data
   1085             results[i] = results[i].copy(deep=False)

Cell In[109], line 25, in <lambda>(row)
     22 grouped_data = cd.groupby(['House Number','Street'])
     24 # Apply the fill_missing_religion function to fill the missing'Religion' values
---> 25 cd['Religion'] = cd.apply(lambda row: fill_missing_religion(row, grouped_data), axis=1)

Cell In[109], line 4, in fill_missing_religion(row, grouped_data)
      2 def fill_missing_religion(row,grouped_data):
      3     # check if the 'Religion' value is missing for the current row
----> 4     if cd.isna(row['Religion']):
      5         # get the group of the lines with the same 'Street Number' and 'Street Name'
      6         add_group = grouped_data.get_group(line['House Number'], row['Street'])
      8         # get the unique non-null 'Religion' values in the group

TypeError: DataFrame.isna() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Please what could be the problem?

Can you add some sample data to your question, i.e. what is cd? The last line of the error traceback shows there's a problem with how you call .isna(). Maybe try something like cd['Religion'].isna() instead.

You have cd.isna(row['Religion']). This is not how df.isna and Series.isna work. You either use cd.isna() or cd['Religion'].isna(). For help beyond that please update your post with a [mre]. Post your data as text, not as a picture. E.g., use cd.head().to_dict() and post between triple backticks (```). Post both input and expected output (i.e. the actual output based on the input provided).

Welcome. Please note that you could trim your code down to a dataframe sample and an if test line of code. Now that I've fixed the code formatting (in a pending edit), it appears that the error raised occurs early in your code, clearly before the groupby/lambda function. See [mre].
